# Can't find i328 folder on CD2 server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis

I have a running windows server 2003 sp2. I’m trying  to add the application roll to the server. The problem is that when I click next in the "configure your server Wizard" it ask me for the CD 2 to find the folder **i328**, when I load that CD I can’t find that folder. Any ideas on how I can add the application roll without the CD2 ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using CD number 1 for the installation. I had the same problem a few years ago.